# Android Studio No LogCat

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio is just killing me. I'm migrating over from Eclipse and am unable to produce LogCat output. I just created a simple hello world app complete with a single line of `System.out.println("hello world");` Regardless of whether I run this on an emulator or on a USB device, I get no LogCat output.

I reinstalled Android Studio, and then I got the correct output for a few executions. Now I'm back to no output. I tried restarting the computer, but this didn't correct anything.

Obviously, I can't reinstall the program every time LogCat output stops being produced, and I can't program without the ability to see console output. I'm beyond frustrated.

Here are a couple of clues:

1. Occasionally, I will get this error:[image]
2. I am unable to run `adb` from the command line. Since I installed my SDK along with Android Studio, I have no idea where the `adb` application exists, so I don't know how to add it to my PATH variable. Even so, I don't think that this has anything to do with why LogCat output isn't produced by Android Studio.

I have tried restarting the LogCat by clicking on the [image]icon, but this does nothing.

I realize that there are *many* other posts on this same type of issue, but the solutions suggested there are not resolving my issue. I am grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Don't use System.out.println. Import android.util.Log and then use

```
Log.e("Randall", "Hello World");
```

Additionally, adb should be found in your

```
sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

folder

Comment: That was it. In Eclipse, I always got away with `System.out.println()`. When I tried using `Log.e()` or `Log.d()` I didn't realize that I wasn't filtering correctly, so my log output was either being swamped by the hundreds of lines in the non-filtered option, or wasn't being picked up correctly in my applications output. I guess I learned something pretty basic about Android logging. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used android studio before, I'm eclipse guy, But maybe you should try Log.d()...